# How to test if p>0.5 for a sample of iid Bernoulli RV?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bernoulli-distribution

I have a sample of iid Bernoulli realization with the probability $p$ unknown and I'd like to be sure that p>0.5

which test can I use to do that?

Thanks

Comment: One Sample Test of Proportions or an exact binomial test if your sample size is small.

Comment: You can also frame it as a (one tailed) [sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test), but that's just a special form of the one sample proportions test / [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) specifically for the $p=\frac12$ case. None of these can really make you 100% *sure* that $p>\frac12$, though. After all, maybe you just got an unusual sample.

Comment: But these tests are not strictly equivalent the test i want to perform